# Rename file with CSV values

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have files that look like that:

```
1989_Footer.gif
1989_Header.gif
260273_Footer.gif
260273_Header.gif
...
```

and I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
1989;10773387
260273;10776516
...
```

I want to rename the files number with the one given in the CSV. The first number in the CSV is the old number and the second one (after the semicolon) is the new number. How can I achive that without touching the text after the underline?

I thought about getting the file name, then search the number in the CSV and replace it with the value in the same line after the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) can simplify the solution. JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jren /?`, or `jren /??` for paged help.

From within a batch script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%A in (rename.csv) do call jren "^%%A_" "%%B_" /fm *.gif
```

From the command line:

```
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %A in (rename.csv) do @jren "^%A_" "%B_" /fm *.gif
```

Comment: Another great answer. Never heard about jren. But this tool is truly awesome. I will probely us this because sometimes i have letters behind the numbers. This Script is far more easy to change than the Script from Magoo. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40908252.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=;" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%r IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%a_*"') DO (
  ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%r_%%s" "%%b_%%s"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40908252.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Read the csv file, using `;` as the delimiter, placing the from-prefix in `%%a` and the to-prefix in `%%b`.

Perform a directory list of files named "%%a_*anything*" in the source directory, tokenise on `_` so that the first token (which must be `%%a`) goes to `%%r` and the remainder-of-name to `%%s`, then rename the file with the prefixes switched.

Assumes that the first `_` in the filename will never be a multiple-`_`

Comment: That is two in a row! I was just about to post a nearly identical answer :-)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the explanation - worked like a charm :)

Comment: Damnit... Just got finished with mine but yours looks way more compact... I am crying a little about 32 nested loops and 2 more separate loops in it... I guess more practice will do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like that (see the explanatory remarks `rem`):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_CSV=%~dpn0.csv" & rem // (path to the CSV file holding the old and new numbers)
set "_LOC=%~dp0"      & rem // (path to the directory containing the files to rename)
set "_PAT=*.gif"      & rem // (pattern of the file name part after the first `_`)

rem // Walk through the CSV file line by line and read old and new numbers:
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=,;" %%K in ("%_CSV%") do (
    rem // Search files whose names begin with the old number and an `_`:
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_LOC%\%%K_%_PAT%"') do (
        rem // Store current file name into variable:
        set "NAME=%%F"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose any `!` in the file name:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Rename current file by replacing the old number by the new one:
        ECHO ren "%_LOC%\!NAME!" "%%L_!NAME:*_=!"
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

**Remove the upper-case `ECHO` command after having successfully tested the script!**

The advantage of this method is that it works even in case the file name part after the first `_` begins with an `_` as well; so a file name `1989__some_name.gif` would become renamed to `10773387__some_name.gif`, so the two consecutive `__` are maintained.